# Unable to Initialize Firebase in my application - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to integrate the Firebase registration in my application by using the version `firebase_auth: ^3.3.6 & firebase_core: ^1.11.0`, upon using this in pubspec and initializing in the app as `final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;`

Do have initialized firebase in main as

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I'm getting an error stating as
`/C:/src/flutter2.8/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'. Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);`

Comment: try to upgrade  firebase_core and firebase_auth to latest versions and then flutter clean , flutter pub get and then flutter pub upgrade and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to upgrade  your flutter using,
`flutter upgrade`

If this is not working than try using lower version of `firebase_auth:2.0.0`

I found this [Link](https://askandroidquestions.com/2021/12/09/i-upgrade-flutter-from-2-5-to-2-8-and-when-i-run-the-app-i-get-the-following-errors/)